# How can I get the color halfway between two colors?

Tags: html, css

I have two colors:

```css
#15293E
#012549
```

How can I find the color that is half way in between them? Is there some way to do this calculation?

Comment: the jquery animate colors plugin does this, as does raphael js. I am sure the answer lies in the source of those.

Comment: Sure, they're made up of 3 hex numbers - 15 29 3E and 01 25 49. Convert each of these numbers to decimal, average them and convert back to hex. Result: 0B2743 or 0B2744, however you want to round off.

Comment: Yes, with JavaScript. But not with HTML or CSS.

Comment: Typically you would want to get the midpoint in HSV space and not in RGB space. In practice for nearby colors it might not matter. I wouldn't be surprised if this is what is done by ColorBlender.

Answer (score 113):

As Mr Lister just said, it is easy to automate the calculation with any programming language :

1. Separate your two colors into their 3 color numbers for [Red, Green, Blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) : (r1,g1,b1) and (r2,g2,b2).

   - For example #15293E, #012549 become ("15", "29", "3E"), ("01", "25", "49")
2. Convert each color string into an integer, specifying explicitly that you are parsing a [hexadecimal-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation of a number.

   - For example ("15", "29", "3E") becomes (21, 41, 62)
3. Calculate the average (r',g',b') = ( (r1+r2)/2, (g1+g2)/2, (b1+b2)/2 ).

   - For example ( (21+1)/2, (41+37)/2, (62+73)/2) = (11, 39, 67)
4. Convert them again to strings , specifying explicitly that you are generating **two-digit** hexadecimal representations (pad with a zero when necessary).

   - For example (11, 39, 67) -> ("0B", "27", "43")
5. Concatenate a hash character followed by the 3 strings

   - For example ("0B", "27", "43") -> **"#0B2743"**

**Edit :** Implementation is not "very easy" as I initially stated. I took the time to write the code in several languages [on Programming-Idioms](http://www.programming-idioms.org/idiom/154/halfway-between-two-hex-color-codes) .

Answer (score 70):

I use this website to do this task for me: [ColorBlender](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/color-blend/).

The mid-color will be `#0B2744`.

Comment: absolutely spot on and easy to use thx

Answer (score 25):

### With LESS

If you use the latest [LESS CSS preprocessor](http://lesscss.org/) then you'll notice there is a function (`mix()`) that does this:

```
mix(#15293E, #012549, 50%)
```

Outputs: `#0b2744`.

Comment: See my answer which works in pure CSS only.

Answer (score 13):

If you need to do this generically, and expect the middle colour to be visually accurate in more cases (i.e. the visual colour and tone of the mid point should "look right" to a human viewer), then as suggested above you may want to convert from RGB to HSV or HSL before calculating the mid point, and then convert back afterwards. This may differ significantly from averaging RGB values directly.

Here is some JavaScript code for the conversion to/from HSL that I found on a brief search, and that on a brief check appears to do the right thing:

<del>github.com/mjackson/mjijackson.github.com/blob/master/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript.txt</del>

https://web.archive.org/web/20170919064926/https://github.com/mjackson/mjijackson.github.com/blob/master/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript.txt

Just apply the rgbToHsl function to your two r,g,b colour vectors, average the two resulting vectors, and apply hslToRgb to that . . .

Answer (score 8):

### Handy-Dandy Function

```
function padToTwo(numberString) {
    if (numberString.length < 2) {
        numberString = '0' + numberString;
    }
    return numberString;
}

function hexAverage() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return args.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        return currentValue
            .replace(/^#/, '')
            .match(/.{2}/g)
            .map(function (value, index) {
                return previousValue[index] + parseInt(value, 16);
            });
    }, [0, 0, 0])
    .reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue + padToTwo(Math.floor(currentValue / args.length).toString(16));
    }, '#');
}

console.log(hexAverage('#111111', '#333333')); // => #222222
console.log(hexAverage('#111111', '#222222')); // => #191919
console.log(hexAverage('#111111', '#222222', '#333333')); // => #222222
console.log(hexAverage('#000483', '#004B39')); // => #00275e
```

Comment: `hexAverage('#000483', '#004B39')` has this has result **"#0275e"** , not really working fine

Comment: The function works nicely, but there's bug in the live demo: `#0088CE, #00B8CF` produces `#0a0ce` instead of `#00a0ce`.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
function colourGradientor(p, rgb_beginning, rgb_end){

    var w = p * 2 - 1;


    var w1 = (w + 1) / 2.0;
    var w2 = 1 - w1;

    var rgb = [parseInt(rgb_beginning[0] * w1 + rgb_end[0] * w2),
        parseInt(rgb_beginning[1] * w1 + rgb_end[1] * w2),
            parseInt(rgb_beginning[2] * w1 + rgb_end[2] * w2)];
    return rgb;
};
```

where p is a value between 0 and 1 specifying how far through the gradient the colour should be and rgb_beginning is the from colour and rgb_end is the to colour. Both are [r,g,b] arrays so you'll have to convert from hex first. This is a simplified version of LESS's mix function which I think is from SASS. For the poster p would be 0.5

Answer (score 5):

In CSS it is as easy as that:

```
color-mix(in srgb, #15293E, #012549);
```

Comment: You may want to note that this is a more recent addition to css, not around at the time of some of these older answers.

Comment: @ScottS But I'm sure that people are still interested in that question. Further, if you open up a new thread with that question it gets closed instantly because the thread here already exists. Therefore, here is the right spot to give up-to-date answers.

Comment: I was not questioning that at all (I'm the one who upvoted your answer), but context helps. This answer is _now_ probably the best answer, but giving people context on when this answer became doable within CSS (since it wasn't previously) would make the answer better.

Answer (score 3):

i just wrote a function that calculates colors between two colors so here it is in case somebody needs it, i think it's quite short and readable, it accepts two colors in hex strings, and the number of colors to calculate in between, returns the colors in an array of hex strings

i took the rgbToHex and hexToRgb functions from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Hope this helps!

```
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}

function hexToRgb(hex) {
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result
    ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
      }
    : null;
}

// returns an array of startColor, colors between according to steps, and endColor
function getRamp(startColor, endColor, steps) {
  var ramp = [];

  ramp.push(startColor);

  var startColorRgb = hexToRgb(startColor);
  var endColorRgb = hexToRgb(endColor);

  var rInc = Math.round((endColorRgb.r - startColorRgb.r) / (steps+1));
  var gInc = Math.round((endColorRgb.g - startColorRgb.g) / (steps+1));
  var bInc = Math.round((endColorRgb.b - startColorRgb.b) / (steps+1));

  for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    startColorRgb.r += rInc;
    startColorRgb.g += gInc;
    startColorRgb.b += bInc;

    ramp.push(rgbToHex(startColorRgb.r, startColorRgb.g, startColorRgb.b));
  }
  ramp.push(endColor);

  return ramp;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an npm module that does this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/color-between

Here's some example usage:

```
const colorBetween = require('color-between');

// rgb format
colorBetween('rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 0.5, 'rgb');
// output: 'rgb(128, 128, 128)'

// rgba format
colorBetween('rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)', 0.5, 'rgb');
// output: 'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)

// hex format
colorBetween('#fff', '#000', 0.5, 'hex');
// output: '#808080'

// mixed format
colorBetween('#fff', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', 0.5, 'hsl');
output: 'hsl(0, 0%, 50%)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python version.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""jcolor_split.py splits 2 hex color values, HEX_COLOR_1 and HEX_COLOR_2, 
    printing the color halfway between the two colors
Usage:     jcolor_split.py HEX_COLOR_1 HEX_COLOR_2
Example: ./jcolor_split.py 3E599C      2E4892
"""
import sys

def jcolor_split(hex_color_1, hex_color_2):

    print()
    print (hex_color_1)
    r1s = hex_color_1[0:2]
    g1s = hex_color_1[2:4]
    b1s = hex_color_1[4:6]
    print(r1s,g1s,b1s)

    print()
    print (hex_color_2)
    r2s = hex_color_2[0:2]
    g2s = hex_color_2[2:4]
    b2s = hex_color_2[4:6]
    print(r2s,g2s,b2s)

    # convert rgb's to ints
    r1 = int(r1s, 16); g1 = int(g1s, 16); b1 = int(b1s, 16);
    r2 = int(r2s, 16); g2 = int(g2s, 16); b2 = int(b2s, 16);
    print()
    print(r1,g1,b1)
    print(r2,g2,b2)
   
    # get the average
    ra = int(round(float(r1+r2)/2))
    ga = int(round(float(g1+g2)/2))
    ba = int(round(float(b1+b2)/2))

    print()
    print(format(ra, 'x')+ format(ga, 'x')+ format(ba, 'x') )

    
 
NUM_ARGS = 2
def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if len(args) != NUM_ARGS or "-h" in args or "--help" in args:
        print (__doc__)
        sys.exit(2)
    jcolor_split(args[0], args[1])
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


sample_run = '''
PS C:\1d\JoeCodeswellHomePage> ./jcolor_split.py 3E599C      2E4892

3E599C
3E 59 9C

2E4892
2E 48 92

62 89 156
46 72 146

365097
PS C:\1d\JoeCodeswellHomePage> 
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

If you so wished you could do it yourself with windows calculator.

1. Open Windows Calculator > View > Programmer
2. Choose the Hex option
3. Enter the Hex value
4. Switch to Dec and write down the value given
5. Repeat for steps 2-4 for the second hex value
6. Calculate the average by adding the two Dec numbers and dividing by 2
7. Enter this value into calculator with the Dec option
   selected then switch to the hex option and voila

**Example:**

- 15293E (HEX) = 1386814 (DEC)
- 012549 (HEX) = 75081 (DEC)
- Mid Point = (1386814+75081)/2
- Mid Point = 730947 (DEC)
- 730947 (DEC) = 0B2743 (HEX)
- **#0B2743**

or use ColorBlender as mentioned above ;)

Comment: Your method won't work in all cases. Try averaging 000100 and 000000 in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here I leave the code that I use in my typescript app

```js
function mixHexColors(color1: string, color2: string) {
    const valuesColor1 = color1.replace('#', '').match(/.{2}/g).map((value) =>
        parseInt(value, 16)
    )
    const valuesColor2 = color2.replace('#', '').match(/.{2}/g).map((value) =>
        parseInt(value, 16)
    )
    const mixedValues = valuesColor1.map((value, index) =>
        ((value + valuesColor2[index]) / 2).toString(16).padStart(2, '')
    )
    return `#${mixedValues.join('')}`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is about 10 years old, but this answer might be interesting for someone who is searching for a CSS-only alternative. Therefore you can just create a CSS gradient between two colors where you set an huge size, e.g. `10000vw` and set the position to `center`:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255,255,0) 0%, rgb(0,0,255) 100%);
background-size: 10000vw;
background-position: center;
```

Based on the percentage of the gradient positions you can also set a ratio to one direction of color.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and cursed one liner:

```js
color = [0,1,2].reduce((c,i)=>c+Math.ceil([color1,color2].map(x=>x.replace('#','')).reduce((a,x)=>a+parseInt(x.length<6?x[i]+x[i]:x[2*i]+x[2*i+1],16)/2,0)).toString(16).padStart(2,'0'),'#');
```

Can handle "#rrggbb", "rrggbb", "#rgb" and "rgb"

Codepen (+more versions): https://codepen.io/micyclebobert/pen/MWLNqBO

Answer (score 0):

Here is my [python](/questions/tagged/python) code that does it (can handle "#rrggbb" and "rrggbb"):

```python
def get_interval_color(color1, color2):

    """Input: color1 as hex number, color2 as hex number,
    both beginning with #, returns hex number color which is a color between
    the two input colors. Returns str."""

    def pad_with_zero( num_str ):
        if len( num_str ) == 1:
            return '0' + num_str
        else:
            return num_str

    if color1.startswith('#'):
        color1 = color1.split('#')[-1]

    color1_a = color1[:2]
    color1_b = color1[2:4]
    color1_c = color1[4:]

    if color2.startswith('#'):
        color2 = color2.split('#')[-1]

    color2_a = color2[:2]
    color2_b = color2[2:4]
    color2_c = color2[4:]

    result_a = (int(color1_a,16) + int(color2_a,16))//2
    result_b = (int(color1_b,16) + int(color2_b,16))//2
    result_c = (int(color1_c,16) + int(color2_c,16))//2

    result_a_hex = pad_with_zero( hex(result_a).split('0x')[-1] ).upper()
    result_b_hex = pad_with_zero( hex(result_b).split('0x')[-1] ).upper()
    result_c_hex = pad_with_zero( hex(result_c).split('0x')[-1] ).upper()

    return '#' + result_a_hex + result_b_hex + result_c_hex
```

Usage:

```python
get_interval_color( '#15293E', '#012549' )
'#0B2743'
```